# Mapping the function signature of the right function in a list in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm building a message formatter that has a bunch of different kinds of messages it can build. Depending on what kind of message it's building, different render functions will be called. Each of these functions can accept different parameters, or optional parameters.

I'm having trouble setting this up and having typescript understand what I'm doing.

Here's some messy code to give you an idea of what I'm after.

```
export enum MessageType {
  Greeting,
  Warning,
}

getFormattedMessage(messageType:MessageType, ...messageParams): string {
  const messageBuilders: {[K in MessageType]: () => string} = {
    [MessageType.Greeting]: () => 'Hi There',
    [ErrorType.Warning]: ({name}) =>
      name ? `${name} is required` : 'That thing is required',
  }

  return messageBuilders[messageType](...messageParams)
}

getFormattedMessage(MessageType.Greeting)
// output, "Hi There
getFormattedMessage(MessageType.Warning)
// output, "That thing is required"
getFormattedMessage(MessageType.Warning, {name: "A fancy hat"})
// output, "A fancy hat is required"
```

There are a few issues with the above code. For instance, I'm having trouble setting up the typescript signatures properly for `getFormattedMessage` or for `messageBuilders`.

I'd like to get to a point where if I type `getFormattedMessage(MessageType.Warning,`  into my editor, vsCode will suggest the variables that show up in the signature of the render function attached to the `Warning` type, and so on.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Here a helper identity function `newMessageBuilder` is used to let the compiler infer the type of messageBuilder implicitly and at the same time constraint its type's lower bound; then use `Parameters<(typeof messageBuilders)[K]>` to constraint the type of `messageParams` according to the value of `messageType`.

```js
export enum MessageType {
  Greeting,
}
export enum ErrorType {
  Warning = 1,
}

function newMessageBuilder<T extends {[K in MessageType | ErrorType]: (...messageParams: any[]) => string}>(messageBuilders: T) { return messageBuilders; }
const messageBuilders = newMessageBuilder({
  [MessageType.Greeting]: () => 'Hi There',
  [ErrorType.Warning]: ({name}: {name: string}) =>
    name ? `${name} is required` : 'That thing is required',
});

function getFormattedMessage<K extends MessageType | ErrorType>(messageType: K, ...messageParams: Parameters<(typeof messageBuilders)[K]>)  {
  return (messageBuilders[messageType] as any)(...messageParams);
}

getFormattedMessage(MessageType.Greeting)
// output, "Hi There

// ERROR Argument of type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'.
// Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type '{ name: string; }'.(2345)
getFormattedMessage(ErrorType.Warning, {a:1})
// output, "That thing is required"

getFormattedMessage(ErrorType.Warning, {name: "A fancy hat"})
// output, "A fancy hat is required"
```

There are of course still issues with the above like the `(messageBuilders[messageType] as any)` that I am <s>ignoring because I found no solution</s> leaving as an exercise for readers.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLLAM7YIYDmwAKgJ5jBwDeAsAFBxwDiUwwMAlogQDT0C+9UJFgIU6AKJQo0MhWr1GAdTxREXAnAC8cAIx86guvQBmyRAGNOERHETAA7llyFgAIWQcANgBNgUAB5iBBAYJB9sagBtAGk4LkwcfCI5SgAfOCkZKFSAXQAuOAAKADoy1CTXAAVVPFRsQrxEUijcgEptAD44bBgoDX5OooqXIg9vPygGuGIOqjhWGGQ1OBHk909ff2wAbjgjCxte1cqxzcnInXsnU42J-yLaBjgo53XUkpY2Tm4C4o6tN0AOQACQ4MwAFv5gECDIwollZORgCUVGoNH9Hog6sB+IUqNiKoVev1uPwAZ1FIw7Di4AB+OAAAwAJAScfx4pFWABHTysHyMuCFIHECF4eAwCEaTkLYC8jj82ECNo7eimcxWDg2OBEGAAMWgqHFYR8b1cATioDCiAiiVGJGRcAyiJyyKGa1cqUKMR4cDKJQ9RBqUDq02DOLCUwCRRgyIgJhO9vGWymbViuU6HQUz0Wy1sw1uyYuUUDDoouTgeEiTVIbVK5Vu4fqKoEarouoNUCNMBNZqIRT7ZZRX3YGja9AA9BO4BBkDAwHPfQAiMGQ6FtqeZABKW4A8lu4ABBKAENBIeDxuCx+RA+Z4QriABG-j2-CBMsQEHgVewHAI2MfLxKBgCA4DAWoKkjGcE2vShbxpIkej6DRXyBEpJ2nXdHwAK2AKw4C8DhIzwLxVjwUgZ0QLwKOwCgLA4EwKIAa0-BxbDAGQKFgDgcF9JofDgIE8HfHwIBwOwvxCDhjgSWDBPmQlgGJZDuFQkoigAJgAZgAFgAVnHdt2E7bte1uIoXQ+NF1G4X0qHvXRyQwmc5wXGBl1FcUrylbgZR5PlgB8Jc2w7Q1jUCwcLOkJEKFRVQbN4ahFMKJdDzgEwmgsCixRgJcnLoTdZ3nRc4FS9LMuyrzpNleV+SXIA)